# How to get SQL statements queued for execution from an objectcontext PRIOR to execution

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to get all create, update, delete, and insert statements that my `ObjectContext` in Entity Framework will execute when I call `SaveChanges()`. I do NOT want to get these statements during or after execution, such as can be achieved with various profiling methods. I want to get these statements without having to execute them whatsoever. Granted, this would mean some incomplete statements given update behaviors, etc. Also, the `ToTraceString()` method is not applicable in my case because I do not have direct access to the queries that have been created; I only have access to the `ObjectContext`. This is, of course, if there isn't a way to get a hold of all previous queries executed on the `ObjectContext`. My code would look something like this:

```
public class myContext : ObjectContext
{
    public myContext() { }
    public string GetQueuedSqlStatements()
    {
       //return queuedsqlstatements
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? From my thin understanding of EF, I imagine that EF does such a thing on the `ObjectServices` when `SaveChanges()` is called. I'm not entirely sure how it achieves this - perhaps it loops through the `ObjectStateEntries` and builds expressions for each ObjectStateEntry then translates them to sql using a provider.

Whatever the case might be, it would be real nice if had access to its 'translate entity to sql statements' functionality.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There was an answer posted a while ago but give it a try:

[How do I view the SQL generated by the entity framework?][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework

Comment: Check the source of Entity Framework http://entityframework.codeplex.com. However - why do you need such functiality? It would break the Entity Framework concept which is to support multiple sources (for example a filestream). I am not sure if it would be possible but I hope my post will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Pellard. Wasn't aware it was available.